# How to change font using jess when creating GUI?

Tags: java, jess

I'm trying to change the font of the JTextArea I created, but it can't work. Please help.
Below are my code in jess(Java Expert System Shell)

```
(defglobal ?*qfield* = (new JTextArea 5 20))
(?*qfield* setFont (new Font "Arial"
        (get-member Font.BOLD)
        30))
```

Comment: Are you on a Windows machine? If not "Arial" may not be loaded

Answer (score 0):

get-member takes two separate arguments: the name of the class and the name of the member. You need to remove the period between them.